# Flutter. How can I make container wider than screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a parallax background for page controller. For that purpuse I need to create a background image that is wider than the screen. I've put it inside a container like this:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
              width: 4000,
              height:  250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/pizza_bg.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat
                  )
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But the problem is that no matter what width I specify, the container (and the image, of course) never get wider than the screen. Is it possible at all?
p.s. I tried to use SizedBox and AspectRatio widgets, and they both give the same result

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this, as an option

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container(
                width: 4000,
                height: 250,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/pizza_bg.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

also you can disable scroll for user and manage scroll position via scroll controller

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: controller, // your ScrollController
      child: Container(
        width: 4000,
        height: 250,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/pizza_bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I'll try to understand the way SingleChildScrollView does the job

Comment: I see you've edited your answer. Yes, I'm using controller from the beginning. It basically just moves the image to a calculated distance to make the effect look like parallax. It works exactly as I needed :)

Answer (score 3):

For images you can use `Transform.scale()`, as found in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.scale.html). Using your example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 10.0,
                child: Container(
                  width: 400,
                  height: 25,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/pizza_bg.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to animate the scale, you can use `ScaleTransition()`, [explained in this page of the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScaleTransition-class.html). For example:

```
/// Flutter code sample for ScaleTransition

// The following code implements the [ScaleTransition] as seen in the video
// above:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
/// AnimationControllers can be created with `vsync: this` because of TickerProviderStateMixin.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat(reverse: true);
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ScaleTransition(
          scale: _animation,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FlutterLogo(size: 150.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** To avoid quality loss in the image, use an image of the size after scaling or a vector graphic as a source.

Comment: It's not a good solution because scaling spoils the quality if the image is not vector

Comment: But if the source image has the size resulting from the scaling factor * initial size no quality is lost, as in the example in my answer. I have checked just now. I will add an advice.